# Jqplot how to highlight graph region on mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot, jqplot-highlighter

I have a custom div in jqplot donut chart. I wanted to highlight particular region of graph on mouse over of that div. How can we do that?

My div with class "custom_legends" have custom legends and want to highlight respective chart region on hover of those legends.

Below is my code:

```
<script class="code" type="text/javascript">;   
  var _chart5_plot_properties;  
  _chart5_plot_properties = {
       title: " ",
       seriesColors: ['.$color_str.'],
       "seriesDefaults":{
          renderer:wcjQuery.jqplot.DonutRenderer,              
          rendererOptions:{
            sliceMargin: 0,
            innerDiameter: 200,
            startAngle: -90,
            barPadding: 0,
            padding: 3,
          }
      },
      grid: {
        shadow: false,
        drawBorder: false,
        shadowColor: "transparent"
      },
      highlighter: {
        show: true,  
        formatString: "%s",
        useAxesFormatters: false,
        showDataLabels: true,
        tooltipLocation: "s"
      },
      legend: {
        show: false
      }
  }

  plot2 = wcjQuery.jqplot("chart2", $chart_style_params, _chart5_plot_properties)';
</script>

<div id="chart2"></div>
<div class="custom_legends"></div>
```